# specify an environment in rails 3 app with thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

I'm using thin to run my rails app on ec2. How do I specify that my ec2 instance is test or prod in thin? Is thin really a good choice for running rails app in production? It's not gonna be a high volume app at least at first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the desired environment to `thin` with either `-e production` on the command-line or `environment: production` in your YAML config-file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you use either Apache or Nginx for your web server which balances requests among a bunch of application servers, typically mongrel, thin or unicorn. This can all happen on the same EC2 instance.

Assuming you know that, using the RAILS_ENV environmental variable to set the environment to production is what you are looking for. You can export this in the bash profile for the entire server if you want, or just specify it every time you boot up a thin instance.

I would also suggest you take a look at [Engine Yard](http://www.engineyard.com/). They provided a fully optimized and configured rails stack on top of ec2 instances for very little($0.01 maybe?) more cost per hour.